# help lines / x-y co-ordinate plane inside a geometric figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new to LaTex, and I'm creating some math problems for my students. I know how to draw a circle using tikz, but is there an easy way to draw the x-y co-ordinate system circumscribed by a circle? I want to use help lines, but I don't want them to extend outside of the circle that I'm drawing. An alternative might be to have the usual square co-ordinate plane equal in width to the circle's diameter but gray out the area outside the circle if that's easier to do (although I'd prefer the first method because the second would waste ink).

Comment: can show, what you try so far? can you show a sketch  (drawn by hand) , what you like to obtain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use clip. Example for ellipse:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 4cm);
    \foreach \x in {-3,...,3} {
      \foreach \y in {-4,...,4}{
      \draw[-] (\x,\y)--(\x,-\y);
      \draw[-] (-\x,\y)--(\x,\y);
      }
   }
  \end{scope}
  \draw (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Clip is working inside a scope but you can have as many scopes as you want.
To add numbers, you can do it outside of the scope, so they can all be seen
and will not be cut by the clip command.

If you need more explanations just ask.

**Edit with Torbjørn T. suggestion:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope} 
   \clip [preaction={draw}] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 4cm);
   \draw [help lines] (-3,-5) grid (3,5); 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I do not add a result because the answer will get too long [I had to make an
horizontal ellipse:P ]. (It is the same with thiner lines inside -for this reason called helplines too-)

Comment: No need for a second answer for this, but a small variation: `\begin{scope}
    \clip [preaction={draw}] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 4cm);
    \draw [help lines] (-3,-5) grid (3,5);
  \end{scope}`

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  Added in the answer.

Comment: @koleygr
What was your first solution?
What does the Torbjorn modification do?

Comment: @AndréC: My first solution is above the bold: (edit). In my original solution just don`t use `help lines` like Torbjorn but using `foreach` loop and `draw` for drawing the lines inside the loop. There would be no difference in the output If I had use `thin` option inside the draw of my first code.

Comment: The point of the `preaction` in my case is that you don't need to draw the ellipse afterward.

Comment: koleygr (and @AndréC for that matter): `help lines` actually corresponds to `very thin,gray`.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. Is there a reason to use `preaction` and not `postaction`?

Comment: @AndréC (I wasn't notified due to the space after the `@`.) With `preaction` the clipping comes after the drawing, so the whole width of the line is shown. With `postaction` the clipping comes first, so half the line is clipped away. (Might be easier to see with a thicker line.) On revisiting this, I realize that a drawback of my suggestion is of course that the grid is drawn on top of the ellipse, which is probably not desired. In that sense a separate `\draw ellipse[x radius=3cm,y radius=4cm];` after the scope is better.

Comment: I think the information listed above will meet my needs. (I want to approximate a map of the night sky for students who don't know polar co-ordinates yet, hence the x-y co-ordinate plane. )

Comment: I think the information listed above will meet my needs. (I want to approximate a map of the night sky for students who don't know polar co-ordinates yet, hence the x-y co-ordinate plane. )

Comment: @Jim... you can accept the answer then if it is ok for your question or write your own answer to accept if you think you will include something more useful about your question.